# Can one learn physics online? And be good at it?

Tags: education

i would like to find a way to study physics online and get academic credentials in it and be able to contribute to the research and publish. I know some topics are experimental and require physical attendance, however there must some subfields in physics that can be studied online. Now there are many online masters in STEM fields like computer science from reputable universities. Is it the same for physics?

Comment: Are you interested in Bachelor or Master level courses? Why do you want this?

Comment: AccidentalTaylorExpansion i am interested in masters level courses,  i want it because i always wanted to study physics as i like it but i am not ready to travel for it or attend physically in university as i am busy.

Comment: You can do many kinds of educational physics experiments without access to fancy lab equipment. And if you don't touch reality in your studies, you won't really comprehend physics.

Answer (score 2):

The Noble Laureate Gerard T'Hooft wrote this article on the topic:

https://www.goodtheorist.science

Comment: Man this is amazing to have a plan of study provided by a nobel prize physicist is impressive and very helpgul thank you very much.